# Navigate Views in a same window in Mac OS Apps

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I'm trying to build an app with two or more `viewControllers` contained in a single window.

Think of System Preferences, the app store, etc: you click on something, and segue to a view in the same window. You also have a back button

Problem is, I have no idea how to achieve this.

I've tried looking for navigation controllers, but those don't exist for OS X apps.
Neither has changing the type of segue.
I've thought of a workaround: superimposing views in now `ViewController` then setting them as `Hidden` or `Visible`, but that doesn't seem very clean...

Comment: Are you using storyboards or xibs?